# how to display html data which are store on string variable with proper format in rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**This is for testing my application**how to display html data which are store on string variable with proper format in rails3?

Comment: What is proper output?  Give some specifics on what you are asking, please.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent Rails from escaping your output, you can use

```
'<div>something</div>'.html_safe
```

or, even better (because it automatically handles nil values)

```
raw '<div>something</div>'
```

Comment: You're welcome - it beats the heck out of `.to_s.html_safe`, imho.